# What does optind do?

Tags: c, getopt

I just saw some code using that and I'm curious how it works, I searched and found it's related to getopt but don't know how they're related. I'm new to programming and I'm currently learning C

this is some parts of the code I found, what does this do?

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Define allowable filters
    char *filters = "bgrs";

    // Get filter flag and check validity
    char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
    if (filter == '?')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid filter.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure only one filter
    if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Only one filter allowed.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != optind + 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];

    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 4;
    }

    // Open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 5;
    }
```

Comment: It is better to see before and later of this code.

Comment: What `optind` does depends on how `optind` is defined in the code. Can you show us?

Comment: All we can say is that it prints an error message and exits if `argc` is not equal to `optind + 2`

Answer (score 3):

From [the POSIX specification of `getopt`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html):

> The variable *optind* is the index of the next element of the *argv*[] vector to be processed. It shall be initialized to 1 by the system, and *getopt*() shall update it when it finishes with each element of *argv*[]. If the application sets *optind* to zero before calling *getopt*(), the behavior is unspecified.

So in your case, the `if` condition is checking that there are exactly two elements of `argv` left to process, because `argc` is the number of elements of `argv` and `optind` is the index of the next unparsed argument.

Answer (score 2):

`optind` is a global variable used by [`getopt(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) .

> `extern int optind;`
> The variable `optind` is the index of the next element to be processed in argv.  The system initializes this value to 1.  The caller can reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning a new argument vector. [...] If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1. Then `optind` is the index in argv of the first argv-element that is not an option.

The snippet you have probably follows a `getopt()` call, which will have populated some other flag variables from the `[flag]` described in that usage example.

It's just a check that there are enough (two) "free arguments" in `argv` after those flags got parsed.